# Passing column names from a different data frame to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to pass to `ggplot` an `x` and a `y` variable where the names come from another data frame.

I thought it would be possible to use the `aes_string()` argument and pass the column names from `data1` but use the data from `data2`.

```
data(iris)
data1 <- iris
data2 <- data

dev.off()
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes_string(
    x = rlang::eval_tidy(colnames(data1)[1]),
    y = rlang::eval_tidy(colnames(data1)[2])
  ), data = data2
  )
```

How can I pass the variable names using something similar to `eval_tidy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) in `aes`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(
    x = !!rlang::sym(colnames(data1)[1]),
    y = !!rlang::sym(colnames(data1)[2])), data = data2)
```

NOTE: `aes_string` is getting deprecated.  So, either we pass unquoted argument as quosure and evaluate (`!!`) or use `{{...}}` or with strings, convert to `sym`bol and evaluate